# Security of an online form

Tags: php, forms, security, email, upload

I have been tasked with creating an online form that sends an email through Swiftmailer. Users can enter their data and attach pdf, doc, jpgs etc. I just want to get confirmation that what i am doing is a good idea :-)

Our server has got SSL and the host handels all that :-)

1. I validate peoples information while they enter it with jq
2. I sanitize the form data with php
3. i validate that the files they have uploadet are actually the files i want, by checking their filename, and looking into their mime type and checking their size (?) i also use the PHP temp function, so the user is not uploading a file they can access later and execute (?)
4. And i send it, either through Gmail with their SSL or something else.

Would this be an alright way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. The good question is: is the way you're sanitizing the data strong?

Comment: What i have done so far is using php's FILTER_SANITIZE_xxx and has worked fine so far! Is that not the way to go or?

Comment: The second point of Frits is exactly what I was thinking at.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two security issues here:

- Someone spamming the form to send you many many email. This probably isn't much of an issue, but if you do encounter it you can a captcha. reCAPTCHA is a decent free captcha service.
- Added virus infected files as attachments. Your mailer can do a virus check, and gmail will likely do one as well.

Make sure you set reasonable limits on max upload size and make sure your validation is tight.

Comment: Good idea with the recaptca! Regading virus, lucky everything is in danish, and the user has to enter alot of information, so it is easy to detect spam or illict attemps! And i hope google will do it, i cant imagine they wont!

Comment: Another good thing is that switfmailer has a whitelist of mime types, and as far as ive read, should be alright at detecing bad stuff, and it wont send if anything is wrong! (as far as ive read!)